# I'd like to know how to monitor tablespaces

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces, size

I'd like to know how to monitor tablespaces.
I don't have much knowledge of Postgres.
When I create a tablespace, how can I measure the tablespace size?
How can I monitor the size of the tablespace so it doesn't overflow? Should I monitor by file system? Would someone have any script and help me with these questions please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot monitor how full a tablespace is, because PostgreSQL has no idea what a file system is or how to measure its size. You will have to monitor your file systems using operating system tools.

Comment: So when I create a tablespace it grows to the limit of the file system? Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is no quota system in PostgreSQL.